# Pool of $N$ ranked items, pick $P$ at random; chances of selecting 3 of top 5 ranks?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $N$ items with a number on them, ranked $1,2,3,4,5,\dots,N$, and I select $P$ items at random.

What are the chances that 3 of the top 5 numbered items are in the $P$ chosen items?

Comment: In how many ways can we select $P$ items from $N$ items? And in how many ways can we select $P$ items from $N$ items such that $3$ of those $5$ (and $P - 3$ of the remaining $N - 5$) are picked?

Comment: Exactly three , or at least three of the top 5?

Comment: *at least three of the top 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{N}{P}$ ways of picking $P$ items from $N$ possibilities.

There are $\binom{N-5}{P}$ ways of picking them so that *none* of the picked items are in the top $5$; there are $\binom{5}{1}\binom{N-5}{P-1}$ ways of picking them so that exactly one is among the top $5$. And there are $\binom{5}{2}\binom{N-5}{P-2}$ ways of picking them so that there are exactly *two* among the top $5$.

So the total number of *bad* picks (picks that do not satisfy the desired conditions) is:
$$\binom{N-5}{P} + \binom{5}{1}\binom{N-5}{P-1} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{N-5}{P-2}.$$

From this, it is easy to compute the probability you want.